# Create new outgoing message with applescript in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: outlook, applescript, osx-lion, sendmail

I'm trying to create a new outgoing message with Microsoft Outlook 2011 for mac, using `AppleScript`.
The following example worked in `10.6.8`:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Hooray for automation"}
    make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Jim Shank", address:"jim.shank@example.com"}}
    open newMessage
end tell
```

On Lion I'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t make class outgoing message.
```

Does anybody have a clue what went wrong there?

I'm using offline Outlook.

Comment: Apparently in more recent versions of Outlook one needs to use 'to recipient' or 'cc recipient' or 'bcc recipient' on the third line of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I'm using a trial version, that has expired. With registered version this script works perfectly. Boo Outlook...I spent on looking into this a couple of hours!

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Hooray for automation"}
    make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Jim Shank", address:"jim.shank@example.com"}}
    send newMessage
end tell
```

This way, it will automatically send it.