# Create a message with attachment in Outlook using applescript

Tags: actionscript, outlook

I'm trying to open a new message window in Microsoft Outloook version 15.6 and populate the fields including an attachment.  Here's my actionscript code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Hooray for automation"}
    make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Jim Shank", address:"jim.shank@example.com"}}
make new attachment at the end of newMessage with properties {file:"/tmp/Invoice INV2 - Paul.pdf"}
    open newMessage
end tell
```

(This message was derived from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521897/create-new-outgoing-message-with-applescript-in-microsoft-outlook)).

However, I get this error: 256:398: execution error: Microsoft Outlook got an error: Error while saving the changed record property. (-2700)

Is it possible to use actionscript to open a new message in the latest version of Outlook?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I attach a file to a new message in Microsoft Outlook via AppleScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052438/how-do-i-attach-a-file-to-a-new-message-in-microsoft-outlook-via-applescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: I needed to add the following line at the front of the script:

```
set x to "/Users/foo/file" as POSIX file
```

See this page for details:
[How do I attach a file to a new message in Microsoft Outlook via AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052438/how-do-i-attach-a-file-to-a-new-message-in-microsoft-outlook-via-applescript)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an applescript one; maybe it'll help?

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook.app"
activate
set theFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:Shared:sp.zip"
set newMessage to make new «class outm» with properties {«class subj»:"Outlook is back"}
make new «class rcpt» at newMessage with properties {«class emad»:{name:"Mark", «class radd»:"blah@blah.com"}}
tell newMessage
    set theAttachment to make new «class cAtc» with properties {file:theFile}
    «event mailsend»
end tell
end tell
```