# How do I attach a file to a new message in Microsoft Outlook via AppleScript?

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

The following script worked fine before upgrading to Office 365 and OSX 10.10:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message
    tell newMessage
        make new attachment with properties {file:"/Users/foo/file"}
    end tell
    open newMessage
end tell
```

But now it gives this error message:

`execution error: Microsoft Outlook got an error: Error while saving the changed record property. (-2700)`

Has the procedure changed or is this a bug in either OSX or Outlook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path must be an **alias** or a **posix file**.

Convert a posix path like this:

```
set x to "/Users/foo/file" as POSIX file
-- or --> set x to "/Users/foo/file" as POSIX file as alias
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message
    tell newMessage
        make new attachment with properties {file:x}
    end tell
    open newMessage
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this as soon as I get hold of a mac again!