# How to generate file that can be saved as draft in Outlook, preferably at huge quantity

Tags: email, web-applications, mime, outlook-restapi, eml

Hey fellow programmers :)

I am currently doing a web application that generates email for users and I am stuck mail app connection. So basically I want to generate emails for users at large quantity and allow them to easily send those out through their own email account. Now I can only think of 2 way, please let me know if there are smarter options!

First one is to connect to email web app like outlook. This one sounds ideal but I am not sure how to. Would appreciate it if anyone can give me some advice and resources to look into!

Second one is to allow users to download the emails as file (potentially .eml or .mime?) and let them open in compose mode. But it seems difficult to work at large scale (my users have to open each file).

I am using MacOS and I tried creating .eml files using python with MIMEMultipart. I added several different headers such as

```
msg.add_header("X-Uniform-Type-Identifier", "com.apple.mail-draft")
```

and

```
msg.add_header("X-Unsent", "1")
```

but I can only open the file in view mode (like opening a previous email) instead of compose mode.

I have already checked this post: [How to generate an email draft that can be opened and sent with Outlook for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537446/how-to-generate-an-email-draft-that-can-be-opened-and-sent-with-outlook-for-mac), seems to be a smart solution but unfortunately I would prefer my users not downloading any applications. So really appreciate it if anyone can give me some ideas on how to tackle this problem! Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for such tasks.